# Multiple definitions found... I have 2 definitions that are similar

Tags: java, maven, cucumber-jvm

I'm running a suite of test automation tests in a Cucumber-JVM & Maven scope. I have specified my step-definitions and glue, so there's no issue there.

The issue is around 2 similar Step Definitions that my IDE and Maven complain seem to be around the error:

```
Multiple definitions found for `some-action-i-want-to-do "actionName" with-specifics "specificsName"`
```

My two Step Functions read like this:

```
@Given("^some-action-i-want-to-do \"(.*)\"$")
public void someActionIWantToDo(String p1) {
  ... etc
}
@Given("^some-action-i-want-to-do \"(.*)\" with-specifics \"(.*)\" $")
public void someActionIWantToDoWithSpecifics(String p1, String p2) {
  ... etc
}
```

So, naturally, when I run the Maven suite, I see warnings... Can anyone suggest a way I can stop or suppress these?

Comment: It's strange for the first method, it's a different regex, why would cucumber match it for `with-specifics`, are you sure that you only have a single `some-action-i-want-to-do-with-specifics` glue ?

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel - Yeah. I'm sure
EDIT: I mean both contain a Regex inside where the some-action reads like 
(\"(.*)\")

Comment: It's clearer now, you have `.*` in the first regex, so it will match `some-action-i-want-to-do "actionName" with-specifics "specificsName"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the `.*` in the first regular expression, it will also match `some-action-i-want-to-do "actionName" with-specifics "specificsName"`

If your actionName is simply made of letters and digits, consider using `\w+`.

`^some-action-i-want-to-do \"(\\w+)\"$`

Therefore it won't accept white spaces or double quotes.

Comment: Thanks, but `Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )`
I'm guessing you meant "\\w"?

Comment: Yes sorry, I didn't write the regex in a java context

Comment: That got it. Thanks =)